# Find the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $M$ in terms of characteristic polynomial of $N$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-functions

Find the characteristic polynomial of the  matrix $M$ in terms of characteristic polynomial of $N$.

$M=\begin{pmatrix}N+V & U\\U^T& I\end{pmatrix}$
where $V=\left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
 n & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
 \ldots& \ldots &\ldots &\ldots\\
 \ldots& \ldots &\ldots &\ldots\\
 \ldots& \ldots &\ldots &\ldots\\
 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
 \end{array}
 \right]_{n\times n}
 $
and  $U=\left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\
 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
 \ldots& \ldots &\ldots &\ldots\\
 \ldots& \ldots &\ldots &\ldots\\
 \ldots& \ldots &\ldots &\ldots\\
 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
 \end{array}
 \right]_{n\times n}$.

**MY TRY**:

I used Schur Complement formula.

We have $\det(xI-M)=\begin{pmatrix}xI-N-V & -U\\-U^T& (x-1)I\end{pmatrix}$

Thus $\det(xI-
M)=\det((x-1)I_n)\times \det ((xI-N-V)-U\frac{I}{x-1}U^{T})$

Since $UU^T=V$ we get

$\det \biggl((xI-N-V)-U\frac{I}{x-1}U^{T}\biggr)=\det \biggl((xI-N-V)-\frac{V}{x-1}\biggr)$

**But I cant proceed further. How do I express  the characteristic polynomial of the  matrix $M$ in terms of characteristic polynomial of $N$ from here?**

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You have already rewritten the formula as
$$
\det((x-1)I_n)\cdot\det((x I - N - V) - V/(x-1))= 
(x-1)^n \det\left((xI - N) - \frac x{x-1}V \right).
$$
Now, note that we can express $\frac x{x-1}V$ in the form $V = uv^T$, where $u = (1,0\dots,0)^T$ and $v = (n\frac x{x-1},0,\dots,0)^T$. Applying the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) yields
$$
\det((x I - N) - uv^T) = (1 + v^T(x I - N)^{-1}u)\det(x I - N)
\\ = \left(1 + \frac{nx}{x-1}[(x I - N)^{-1}]_{1,1}\right)\det(x I - N),
$$
where $[A]_{i,j}$ denotes the $i,j$ entry of the matrix $A$. Putting everything together, we have
$$
\det(x I- M) = (x-1)^n \left(1 + \frac{nx}{x-1}[(x I - N)^{-1}]_{1,1}\right)\det(x I - N).
$$